# Calling main function from java stored procedure

Tags: java, plsql, java-stored-procedures

I have loaded the class file of a java program (that fetches data from an excel file and pushes it to a database and making connection to database using values from properties file) into the SQL developer.

Now I am trying to invoke the main method of the class file as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dataset
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'data_design_1.main()';
```

It gives the following error:

```
Error: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
Error(3,1): PLS-00311: the declaration of "data_design_1.main()" is incomplete or malformed
```

Could anyone tell me why is this error occurring??

Thank you.

Comment: Wild guess: parentheses aren't part of the 'name' of a method?

Comment: Is `data_design_1` the fully qualified path to the class?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the declaration of your main is this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

so the declaration of your PL/SQL wrapper is wrong.

You haven't posted the Java code
Maybe I'm wrong.